# Working With Json in swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to get long_name from this JSON file I can just access 'results' with this code:

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.7229513,51.3566039&language=fa&key=AIzaSyBXOPT1jEYizWZHOKLwv4dhacgYTcmn3I4")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!)

        }
        else{

            if let urlcontent = data {

                do{
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlcontent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]

                print(jsonResult["results"]!)
                    if let jsonResult = jsonResult["results"] as? [String: Any] {
                        if let address_components = jsonResult["address_components"] as? [String: Any] {
                            print(address_components)
                            if let long_name = address_components["long_name"] as? [String: Any] {
                                    print(long_name)
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }
            catch{
                print("json failed")
            }

        }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

But I'm just getting result this is my JSON file: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.7339859%2C51.3393980&sensor=true_or_false&language=fa

Comment: Can you catch error (`catch let error`), printout that error and add it to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result key contains `Array` as value not `Dictionary` so simply change `[String:Any]` to `[[String:Any]]` and then access `address_components` from the each dictionary objects of resultsArray, now `address_components` is also array of dictionary and `long_name` is inside that dictionary. So try like this.

```
if let resultsArray = jsonResult["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {
     for dic in resultsArray {
         if let addressArray = dic["address_components"] as? [[String:Any]] {
              for address in addressArray {
                   if let longName = address["long_name"] as? String {
                        print(longName)
                   }
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm new in swift can you please write complete code for me for getting long_name for address component? thanks in advance